# pandas: changing timestamp in cell results in incorrect value

Tags: numpy, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame where I am trying to change one of the cells' timestamps to a different timestamp. However, I'm not getting the result I expect. Here's what I have:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"d": [np.datetime64('2013-07-14T10:30:30.521Z'), np.datetime64('2013-07-21T10:30:30.521Z')]})
>>> df
                           d
0 2013-07-14 10:30:30.521000
1 2013-07-21 10:30:30.521000
>>> df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc("d")] = np.datetime64('2013-08-29T10:30:30.521Z')
>>> df
                              d
0    2013-07-14 10:30:30.521000
1 1970-01-01 00:22:57.772230521
```

As the example illustrates, the timestamp I get for `df.loc[1, "d"]` is not the one I am assigning to that cell. I don't understand this behavior or where I'm going wrong. Is there some other way I need to be changing the value of a timestamp?

**Edit**: the above is just a simple example. My actual df has many columns, not just 1. I'm using pandas version 0.16.1 (and can't change the version).

Comment: Your sample code works as expected for me.  What versions of pandas/numpy are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your df has only one column you can do it this way:

```
In [29]: df
Out[29]:
                        d
0 2013-07-14 10:30:30.521
1 2013-07-21 10:30:30.521

In [30]: df.iloc[-1] = pd.to_datetime('2013-08-29T10:30:30.521Z')

In [31]: df
Out[31]:
                        d
0 2013-07-14 10:30:30.521
1 2013-08-29 10:30:30.521
```

**UPDATE:** if you have multiple columns in your DF:

```
In [47]: df
Out[47]:
                        d  a
0 2013-07-14 10:30:30.521  1
1 2013-07-21 10:30:30.521  1

In [48]: df.loc[df.index[-1], 'd'] = pd.to_datetime('2013-08-29T10:30:30.521Z')

In [49]: df
Out[49]:
                        d  a
0 2013-07-14 10:30:30.521  1
1 2013-08-29 10:30:30.521  1
```

Comment: Sorry - I should have clarified. The above was just a simple example; my actual df has many more columns.

Comment: That still gives me the wrong timestamp. Probably has to do with my pandas version - but I can't change that.

Comment: @LateCoder, what version do you have?

Comment: you may want to replace `df.ix` with `df.loc`

Comment: 0.16.1 (it's added to my question in the edit above)

Comment: How can I reference the "last" row with loc?

Comment: @LateCoder, try to use `pd.to_datetime()` instead of `np.datetime64()`